# Careers Profile badges

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Has anyone written a badge for Careers 2.0 to include on your personal site/blog? Something like [flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105717/dov/flair). I would like to include a link to mine.

It would be nice if it could be configurable like [Facebook Badges](http://www.facebook.com/badges/profile.php), so you could decide which information would display.

Comment: Closest thing I found is the "PDF Preview" - it has minimal dynamic data.

Comment: What parts would you like to show up on it?

Comment: I figured the profile picture, and the rest could be customizable, like Facebook does (updated post).